# Error while confirm by the mail

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

```
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

Url:

```
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email as allauthemailconfirmation

url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation, name="account_confirm_email"),    
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

I just read about [this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L190), but I don't understand how to modify my code

Traceback:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
Internal Server Error: /rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTU:1bn1OD:dQ_mCYi6Zpr8h2aKS9J9BvNdDjA/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 159, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 133, in render_to_response
    template=self.get_template_names(),
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 146, in get_template_names
    "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of "
ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
Internal Server Error: /rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTU:1bn1OD:dQ_mCYi6Zpr8h2aKS9J9BvNdDjA/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 159, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 133, in render_to_response
    template=self.get_template_names(),
  File "/home/k/klimaku9/justforfree.ru/public_html/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 146, in get_template_names
    "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of "
ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @daniel-roseman added

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `(?P<key>\w+)` should be something like `(?P<key>.+)`.