# django-rest-auth handling expired confirmation email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using django-rest-auth and django-allauth to handle user authentication in my rest api. When a user tries to verify their email after the link has expired, I get an unpleasant error page.

[image]

Please, how can I display a better error page or send a message telling them it wasn't successful because the link had expired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand, your error is coming from `django-allauth`, not from your project. Reason for the error is that you did not include `allauth.url` in your main `urls.py`(will explain more in later section).

### Possible solutions

#### First Solution

Add `allauth.urls` in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

#### Second Solution

If you go deep into the problem, you will see the error is saying `NoReverseMatch` error, which occurs when there is a url name which is not found in project ie `account_login`. Now this error is coming from template at at [**`allauth base template`**](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/base.html#L29).

Judging by your code, this error is occurring due to these line:
(*I took the liberty to check your github codebase as it was opensource.*)

```
if not email_confirmation:
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    try:
        email_confirmation = queryset.get(key=key.lower())
    except EmailConfirmation.DoesNotExist:
        # A React/Vue Router Route will handle the failure scenario
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/failure/')  # <-- Here
```

It is pointing to a wrong url which does not exist in system. Please check [**`django-rest-auth urls`**](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/urls.py).

So one fix here is to provide a template response here with a view like this:

```
# in accounts/api/urls.py
path('failure/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='api_failure.html'))
```

Another solution is to provide [**`custom 404 template`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view) like this:

```
# accounts/api/views.py
def handler404(request, exception, template_name="your_custom_404.html"):
    response = render_to_response(template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response

# root urls.py

 handler404 = 'accounts.api.views.handler404'
```

Answer (score 1):

write your own custom exception handler

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
# Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
# to get the standard error response.
response = exception_handler(exc, context)

# Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
if response is not None:
    response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

return response
```